# BSOD after installing old driver in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, drivers, bsod

I have installed an older version of [BlindWrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlindWrite) (I know it was a stupid thing to do)  on my Windows 8.1 laptop. During the reading of a DVD, a [BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) showed, saying DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. When trying to boot up, it shows a BSOD again with error 0xc000021a.

Further problems I have:

- safe-mode won't start when running it from the system repair section
- using system restore didn't work either
- disabling driver signature enforcement didn't help
- using System Refresh/Reset or reinstalling Windows is not a solution

Further details:

- it has crashed before in these circumstances but booted up fine after that
- this time, while reading the DVD I had my Nexus phone connected to the laptop. The ADB driver failed while reading the DVD when trying to run an application from Eclipse
- my laptop is an Asus G74Sx
- RAM and disks are fine

Now the way I see it, **I would need to somehow uninstall the driver installed by BlindWrite using only the command prompt available in the Repair menu. Or somehow tell Windows not to load that driver. How would I do this?**

Comment: This will require a second installation of Windows, load the hive of the original installation, this will allow you to delete the driver from being loaded.

Comment: You can booting your PC using Bart PE and modify the registry to not load the driver.

Answer (score -1):

Set DisablePagingExecutive at registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
"DisablePagingExecutive"=dword:00000001
```

maybe help ...

And save and show your mini-dump.

Comment: (-1) this answers nothing. Setting this is required to capture stacks with xperf because this keeps some data in RAM instead of paging it out.